# Срабатывание CanClose у команды закрытой вкладки на Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ribbon

Есть приложение с набором периодически открывающихся/закрывающихся вкладок на ленте. Главная модель представления содержит информацию о перечне вкладок, выбранной вкладке и команду для создания новых вкладок:

```
public sealed class MainVm : ViewModel
{
    // создает новую вкладку, добавляет ее в коллекцию и делает выбранной
    public ICommand OpenNewTabCommand { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<TabVm> Tabs { get; }

    public TabVm SelectedTab { get; set; } // PropertyChanged
}
```

Модель представления вкладки предоставляет наименование и команду для закрытия вкладки:

```
public sealed class TabVm : ViewModel
{
    private bool isClosed;

    private void HandleClose()
    {
        Parent.SelectedTab = Parent.Tabs.FirstOrDefault(_ => _ != this);
        Parent.Tabs.Remove(this);
        isClosed = true;
    }

    private bool CanClose()
    {
        if (isClosed)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"{Name}: вызван CanClose после закрытия вкладки");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public MainVm Parent { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public ICommand CloseCommand { get; }

    public TabVm(MainVm parent, string name)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Name = name;

        CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(HandleClose, CanClose);
    }
}
```

Реализация ICommand:

```
public sealed class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute();
    }
}
```

Представление главного окна:

```
<RibbonWindow ...>
    <Ribbon ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Новая вкладка" Command="{Binding OpenNewTabCommand}"/>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Button Content="Close" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
    </Ribbon>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Если я создам новую вкладку, а потом закрою ее, то в Output будут сыпаться сообщения о вызове CanClose для уже закрытой вкладки. Все это будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока до модели представления вкладки не доберется сборщик мусора. Вероятно, это происходит из-за подписки на событие RequerySuggested у CommandManager в команде.

Есть ли какие-нибудь предложения по обходу этой ситуации?

Один из вариантов - сделать команду Disposable. Внутри самой команды собирать подписчиков в список, а в Dispose - отписываться. Не очень хороший вариант, т.к. придется либо дергать Dispose через reflection автоматически, либо следить за этим всем и высвобождать вручную.

Comment: А что плохого то? CanExecute может вызывать и до отображения и после закрытия. Это ожидаемое поведение в WPF.

Comment: @Monk, плохо то, что в некоторых случаях он лезет к уже высвобожденному контексту, в результате чего получается ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: В большинстве случаев проще проверять всё это в CanExecute, ибо это его ответственность. Либо, CanExecuteChanged не должен цепляться к CommandManager, а только к явно связанным с ним лично событиям.

Comment: @Monk, ну да, как вариант, отлавливать Exception в CanExecute. Не цепляться к CommandManager не вариант, т.к. тогда придется делать намного больше телодвижений.

Comment: Так в этом и весь смысл. Либо вы вручную рулите доступностью, либо не жалуетесь на позднее уничтожение и некорректные вызовы.

Comment: @Monk, я предполагал, что раз уж кнопки пропали из зоны видимости, то и событие не должно возникать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты обхода этой ситуации, которые я придумал (для Disposable моделей представления):

1. Disposable команда. Собираем подписчиков, а в Dispose отписываемся.
2. Проглатывать все исключения в CanExecute.
3. Передавать в команду модель представления. Внутри команды определять, что модель представления уже не должна существовать и возвращать false.

Я остановился на варианте номер 3.